# Need to scroll image past its edge in a picturebox

Tags: c#, graphics, crop, picturebox

I have a specific crop selector I am trying to design.

1. Picture box of 400 x 400 pixels.
2. Circle 200 pixel in center drawn over image so enable the user to crop what inside the circle.

I have this working but what I cannot work out to do is to  move the image outside of it's boundaries.
i.e.   I want to move the image effectively to position -100, -100 in the picture box so that the circle will appear over the lower left of the real image.

Comment: You will have to draw it.

Comment: There are several SizeModes but none will aloow you to freely place the Image. You will indeed have to Draw it. But: What is it you __really__ want? Why not move the cirlce??